# No gtm.linkClick in Google Tag Manger preview for CTRL Click on image

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm trying to set up an image link click tracking event, but there's no gtm.linkClick popping up in the Google Tag Manager preview when I CTRL + click an image. Please see below:

[Google Tag Manager preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h78zJ.jpg)

Could somebody help me please?

Thanks,
Simon.

Comment: Hi Simon, you have provided way too little information. Maybe you forgot to enable built-in variables but there is no way to know unless you post more information about your setup. To get better and faster answers have a look at this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Look at the configuration of the built in variables in GTM. Maybe you have to check the checkbox for Click URL. You can configure the variables by clicking on "Variables" > "Configure".

[image: Click on Variable > Configure]

Comment: That's done it. Thank you!

Another question: Do you know if it's possible to only fire the tag once per session, or once per user please?

Comment: @SHMC you'll have to set a cookie with expiration of your definition of session or user and check if the cookie exists or not, if it exists you can update the expiration and if not you can set the cookie and fire the tag.